# how to get the content of a page via url in twig templates or in twig extension?

Tags: sulu

So there is the twig function `sulu_content_load('1234-1234')` to get the content via `uuid`. Is there a way to get to the content of a page via url, like `/team/member-1` or `/about-us`?

Answer (score 0):

there is currently no twig extension for this - but you could write your own and use following services:

1. "sulu.content.resource_locator.strategy_pool" to get the resourcelocator strategy by your webspace key

```
$resourceLocatorStrategy = $this->resourceLocatorStrategyPool->getStrategyByWebspaceKey("my-webspace-key");
```

2. Get the uuid of the page

```
$uuid = $resourceLocatorStrategy->loadByResourceLocator("/test-1", "my-webspace-key", "de");
```

3. Use "sulu_document_manager.document_manager" to get document of the page

```
$document = $documentManager->find($uuid, "de");
```

After this the question is what would you like to do with this document? Do you need some informations out of the content? Or maybe something else?